# table design and related sqli query

Tags: php, mysql

> There are two drop down lists in the page

1. Centers (displays all the centers)
2. Courses (displays all the courses)

> When the user selects a center from drop down menu   the result should
>   display all the courses run by that center only
>
> Similarly when the user selects a course name from the drop down list,
>   it displays all the centers running that Particular course

Now the problem is

1. how to design the tables and
2. how to describe relationship between them
3. What should be related SQL query to achieve the above  (highlighted)  functionality?

Comment: This sounds more like a javascript problem.

Comment: no, its related to sql tables and related query

Answer (score 0):

schema

```
centers (id, name)
courses (id, name, id_center)
```

display all the course related to a center

```
select id, name 
from courses 
where id_center= 'user_center_selection';
```

display all the center related to a course (using in and subselect )

```
select id, name 
from centers
where id in (select id_center 
          from courses where  id = 'user_course_selection')
```

or using an inner join

```
select id, name 
from centers 
inner join courses on 
      (courses.id_center = enters.id and courses.id = 'user_course_selection')
```